# How can I calculate the allowable range for reduced cost (RC) and shadow price (Pi) in gurobi python?

Tags: python, gurobi

So I'm trying to do a sensitivity analysis with Gurobi python, I found the optimal values alongside with the shadow prices (`cons1.Pi`) and the reduced costs (`x.RC`). But I don't know how to calculate their allowable increase and decrease. I would appreciate it if someone could help!!

Basically I am trying to get these two tables filled out:

```
Variable | Final_Val | Reduced_cost | Obj_Coeff | Allowable_increase | Allowable_decrease

Constraint | Final_Val | shadow_price | RHS | Allowable_increase | Allowable_decrease
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about two attribute querying functions: `x.SAObjLow` & `x.SAObjUp` which will give the maximum and minimum value that the objective coefficient of x1 can take before the optimal solution changes. And for constraints you can use `constrs[t].SARHSLow` & `constrs[t].SARHSUp`. Hope it helps out you as well.

I would strongly recommend anyone new to gurobi (like me) to visit [this](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/attributes.html) webpage.